# Modifications and alterations in the state of chemical equilibrium

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

Let us consider that we have a mixture of gases, considered ideal, that is in balance. Like, for example,

$$3\ce{NO} (g) \rightleftharpoons \ce{N2O} (g) + \ce{NO2}(g)$$

If we consult the thermodynamic tables, we can appreciate that the reaction is exothermic and exergonic.

This thermodynamic state of chemical equilibrium can be altered depending on various parameters, such as temperature or pressure.

1. Modification of the temperature: If we increase the temperature, the system moves in the endothermic direction, that is, towards the formation of products. This rule is well known, but I would like to be able to justify it by mathematical reasoning. I have thought about Van't Hoff's equation, but since I do not know the value of the equilibrium constant at a certain temperature, I have not been able to use it.
2. Modification of the volume. This is where I have the most doubts. I need to determine which way the system is moving. I know that the system moves to where it is least bothered, in this case, to the right. But, again, I wonder if this can be justified mathematically. I seem to remember my physical chemistry teacher doing it based on the definition of K (considering partial and constant pressures of fugacity)
3. If a non-inert (reactive) gas is added to the equilibrium mixture Here I know that there are several cases to distinguish:
   3a) If the total volume is not modified
   3b) If the total pressure remains unchanged
   3c) If the temperature remains unchanged 
   3d) If the intensive variables can be modified
   But, really, this one I have no idea how to reason with.
4. If we add an inert gas, any noble gas, I'm not sure what to do either.

I know the question is a long one. But, I have tried to reason out everything I know about the subject (basically, Le Châtelier's principle). But, I need to justify it on the basis of mathematical reasoning, since my teacher has told me that, in some cases (which are not many), Le Châtelier fails.

Comment: Le Châtelier is an universal principle. Did your teacher give *one* valid counterexample?

Comment: What do you want to get ? What do you mean by mathematical reasoning ? By the way you have chosen a poor example. I am pretty sure that NO will never react to produce N2O and NO2, whatever your thermodynamics calculations.

Comment: @Maurice - at high pressures, this reaction is well known to occur. See, for example, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12653205

Comment: @Karl  The addition of nitrogen gas, at constant temperature and pressure, to an equilibrium mixture containing N2, H2 and NH3

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar I read about that one now, too. If you add nitrogen at constant pressure, you lower the partial pressure of hydrogen so much that the reaction runs backwards. Quite trivial, and totally expected from LeChatelier.

Comment: nother example cited by Cheung (2004) is the dimerisation of NO2. Consider an equilibrium mixture of NO2 and N2O4 in a sealed container. When we raise the temperature, we may expect that the position of equilibrium to shift to the left since the backward reaction to form NO2 is endothermic. However, there is also an increase in the total pressure of the system when the mixture is heated. Again, by LCP, the pressure increase would likely shift the position of equilibrium to the right to the side with less moles of gaseous molecules. @Karl